# How can I design my FPGA power supply if I don't know how it will be used exactly?

Tags: power, fpga, current

I'm designing a little dev board for FPGA experimentation using the Cyclone IV EP4CE10 but I am having a bit of trouble estimating the power requirements. I understand this depends almost completely on the usage and configuration of the device but since I'm a bit new to this and really have no idea how and what I'm going to be using it for, (because, you know, it's a dev board) I could use some advice on what would be "enough" for the different power rails. I won't be doing anything extreme, I believe, but I would like to have a bit of headroom for experimentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using Altera's tools for that? I've no practical experience here (I've some minor experience with Xilinx), but [PowerPlay Early Power Estimator](http://www.altera.com/support/devices/estimator/pow-powerplay.jsp) seems helpful. You can chose `Maximum` for the `Power Characteristic`, if you want some headroom for experiments.

If you have a real design for which you want to estimate the power consumption, you can use PowerPlay Power Analyzer, part of the Altera Quartus II system. They claim it has 20% accuracy.

Comment: I did try to use that but got an error ("Compile error") when I loaded it into Excel. This is probably because I'm using it on a Mac with Office:mac 2011.

Comment: That's a very likely reason, unfortunately I only have Pages on my Mac at work, so I'm not able to confirm it right now.

Comment: You can wing it and use 1A supplies for each rail.  You may be able to use LDOs for all of these.  This will likely be plenty for a small Cyclone 4 device.  Unless you have a fast clock (100MHz+) running lots of circuitry, your power requirements will be pretty modest in one of these parts.

Comment: Pro tip: put a 10 mohm (.010 ohm) 1% series resistor in series with each LDO output, and you can measure the current very accurately with a DMM.

Answer (score 1):

National Semi's [SIMPLE SWITCHER online tool](http://www.national.com/analog/power/simple_switcher) ("WEBENCH designer") allows you to design a power supply for a specific FPGA.

Beyond that you could search online for designs/schematics of other similar dev boards to see what they used.

For example, I have a mini/barebones FPGA board based on the EP2C5T144 (from eBay); I believe the 3.3V regulator it uses is rated at around 800mA. Compared to the big Altera DE2 board I have which is loaded full of all sorts of I/O devices, it uses an LM2676 3.3V switching regulator rated at 3A.

I'm still pretty new to this too so I don't know all the fancy equations to calculate FPGA power requirements. Also, I believe there's some sort of power estimator tool in Quartus II, but that's proably specific to a specific design/configuration.

Hopefully the above gives you some frame of reference.

Comment: Another (naive) thought I had was what about multiplying the number of I/O pins by the max current allowed per pin? Kind of a 'worst-case' scenario.

Comment: The problem is that the 1.2V VCCINT (core voltage I believe?) uses a lot of current as well if I'm not mistaken. 3.3V is only for I/Os and that maximum can be approximated rather easily, I assume.

Comment: Well for comparison sake, that big "DE2" board uses two AME1117 (1-amp) LDOs in parallel for the 1.2V VCCINT.

Comment: That's good to know! At least I'm starting to get the idea of which ballpark we're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You could use bench supplies for your prototype during development. When you know how much current the various supplies require you can design them for your production board, adding a bit of capacity for future enhancements.

Comment: I doubt there will be a production board for this since I just want to mess around and learn stuff. Problem is that I only have one bench power supply output.